# delete[] with different type undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++

I am wondering if this is undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  auto* p = new uint8_t[32];
  float* c = reinterpret_cast<float*>(p);
  delete[] c;
}
```

In the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.delete)
there is

> If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.79 If not, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: this means that the syntax of the delete-expression must match the type of the object allocated by new, not the syntax of the new-expression.  — end note ]

So interpreting the somewhat unclear phrase

> this means that the syntax of the delete-expression must match the type of the object allocated by new, not the syntax of the new-expression

I can say the above is Undefined Behavior, correct?

Comment: You're quoting the wrong paragraph. The next paragraph is what says the types must match, or it's undefined.

Comment: In your particular case, the undefined behavior is "harmless" (if it can ever be harmless to invoke UB) and so it could in principle be well-defined. But think about what would happen if destructors _were'nt_ trivial as in your example. What's the compiler supposed to do in that case? It must invoke _some_ destructor, only just which one is the correct one, and how would it deal with the arguably incorrect blob of memory (which is really some other type) that it refers to?

Comment: Be aware that your use of `reinterpret_cast` has implementation defined behavior. When converting between (unrelated) pointer types, alignment could differ eg.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, the behaviour is undefined.

The pointer passed to `delete[]` must be the same type as the one you get back from `new[]`.

Note that for `delete` and `new`, the pointer submitted to `delete` is allowed to be related by polymorphism.

Comment: Standard link that says this: [\[expr.delete\]#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.delete#3)

Comment: Should this be detectable by a sanitizer? I checked the snippet with `-fsanitize=undefined,address`, that didn't catch anything.

Comment: I couldn't detect it as well with `-fsanitize=leak,address` (coliru...)

Comment: well, on a number of platforms it might still generate legal code that's why AS wouldn't detect it. valgrind might not either. the issue is that in certain situation the value of `c` wouldn't be same as value of `p`, or that implementations tracks memory allocation in more discriminating way, that's where C++ standard comes with UB.

Comment: Quite. This case may work absolutely fine in 99% of implementations; most of them (certainly those built upon malloc/free) are likely to care only about the address, not about the type or array-ness. But for implementations that do care, it might be an issue. That lack of a guarantee of correctness across platforms/implementations is enough for it to be marked as UB.

Comment: Interesting. Seems someone found my now deleted comment objectionable.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Did they, or did a moderator silently delete it?

Comment: Same thing, no? That someone could have had power to abuse beyond mere flagging.

Comment: @Zastai Even on implementation that use malloc and free this kind of delete may fail because the pointed base subobject may not be at the same address as the complete object: type casting a pointer may change its value.

Comment: @Oliv Fair point, although that's perhaps unlikely to be the case for builtin types like int and float.

Comment: @Zastai: I'm not sure you can be so certain about that; e.g. architectures with separate floating point processors.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Even on those, you eventually end up in `::operator new`. C++ leaves fairly little room for implementations that have separate memory spaces for separate types (other than functions, which do live in their own space)

Comment: @Zastai I agree with you, if a fundamental type had a base type it would not be fundamental! (I was referring to the question in the title)

Comment: I am afraid you are partly wrong: there is no polymorphic provision for `delete[]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520199/147192

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Well you learn something new every day! I've amended and wiki'd the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba: To be honest, it's not clear to me why this is not supported. I would expect that if `delete` can accommodate polymorphism, then so can `delete[]`. It's possible that the fact that pointer arithmetic doesn't work on a `Base*` to `Derived[]` means that nobody saw any use in supporting polymorphism for `delete[]`.

Comment: The lack of usable pointer arithmetic would prevent proper destructor invocation, wouldn't it? So allowing polymorphism wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the code in indeed Undefined Behavior. The phrasing means that it would still be UB when you would rewrite it as

```
int main() {
  void* p;
  {
     using T = uint8_t;
     p = new T [32];
  }
  {
    using T = float;
    T* c = reinterpret_cast<float*>(p);
    delete[] c; // The behaviour is still undefined.
  }
}
```

IOW, the types really have to match exactly, not just in name.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my putting in that comment; just in case someone reading quickly interprets your snippet as a solution. And an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

**It is undefined behavior** to call `delete[] p;` if `p` has a different type that what `new[]` returned.

Notably:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
struct Derived: Base { int a; };

int main() {
    Base* p = new Derived[5];
    delete[] p;
}
```

Is *also* undefined behavior.

---

@Justin provided the relevant standard quote in a comment [see it here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.delete#3):

> **5.3.5 [expr.delete]**
>
> (3) In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. **In the second alternative (*delete array*) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.**

Note how there is no provision for polymorphic relationship in the *delete array* case I emphasized; contrary to the *delete object* case.